# XMPP Get number of room members without connecting to a room

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I have: ios app;
Server: openfire;
Framework: xmppframework from Robby Hanson.

The logic of the app is when user has logged in, the app will push him into a random room which has the fewest number of members.

The app successfully gets a list of all rooms on start from the server.
But I need to know which of these rooms have an empty place for a user!

There is a method called "fetchmemberslist", but it only returns you a list of members of a room when you are connected to that room.

I need something that will do the same without connecting to a room.

Think if I have 1000 rooms. Using this method the app needs to connect to every room, set delegate, activate, wait for IQ, remove delegate, deactivate and at the and go thru an array to find one with the fewest members.
Isn't it too much to do?

I have dig over the whole internet and everything leads to getting a member list when you are connected to a room.

Is there a way of doing this without connecting a room.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1) `fetchMemberList:` queries room members, not list of people who are present in room now. Are you really want members, not online users count? Anyway, if you are room admin, this query works without joining room.

2) If you want to query online users, you should use different query - see http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-roomitems

3) Also, no one can forbid you to implement room members/onlines count on the server side and create custom query like `<iq id='123' type='get'><freeroom xmlns='my:freeroom:query' /></iq>` with response of room JID like `<iq id='123' type='result'><freeroom xmlns='my:freeroom:query'><jid>roomname@conference.example.com</jid></freeroom></iq>` where roomname was found by server itself.

Comment: Thank you, Vitalyster! Your second trick helped!
A little comment regarding fetchmemberslist

I am the admin and owner of the room, but still when I call fetchmemberslist on it (without joining it), I get error 401 not-authorized
But! This method does not do what I need. It only return members.

Comment: While studing disco#items I ran against disco#info that returns an [extended result](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-roominfo) with a number of occupants per room and a lot of other stuff. I do not need that other stuff. Is it possible to create a query that will return only a specific field? I am interested in <field var='muc#roominfo_occupants' label='Number of occupants’>. I tried some ways, but I still get the whole extended result.

Comment: And another thing. I first get a list of rooms, then I send disco#info to every room.
Can I join two IQs that will query a list of rooms with number of it’s occupants? THANK YOU!!!

Comment: 1) managing member list should work without joining room, I'm not sure it is defined in XEP-0045, but prosody and ejabberd definitely allow it, maybe it is openfire problem.
2) what is the problem to parse extended result and get number of occupants? You can make it with with XPath queries or something like. In fact, every XMPP library parse XML packets and finds required info.
3) No, you can't send one IQ to many rooms, but you can extend server side with custom IQ, as I describe in first answer.

Comment: Thank you, Vitalyster! It helped a lot! Probably there is also a way to get a stack of occupants sorted by the time when each of them has joined the room? Disco-roomitems returns a list that is sorted by some mystery way. Neither by joinig time nor alphabetically. Thank you!!!